Has Azerbaijan signed a contract to purchase JF-17s from Pakistan?
There is news floating around that Azerbaijan ahas signed a contract with Pakistan to purchase JF-17s. See Azerbaijan confirms purchase of JF-17 fighters.
However, the article JF-17C multirole aircrafts presented to President Ilham Aliyev on the "Official web-site of the President of the Republic of Azerbaijan" doesn't confirm anything.
Has Azerbaijan signed a contract to purchase JF-17s from Pakistan?


Has Azerbaijan singned a contract to purchase JF-17 from Pakistan?

The images do not support this.
The aircraft shown bear Pakistani markings.
The link in question claims...

The jets have already been integrated into the arsenal of Azerbaijan's Air Force.

Their photographs contradict this.
The pictures of the JF-17 on the ground obscure its markings, but we can see on its engine inlet covers the emblem of No. 16 Squadron of the Pakistani Air Force. No. 16 Squadron flies JF-17s.


The accompanying pictures of a flying JF-17 have Pakistani Air Forces roundels.

This is the roundel of Azerbaijan.

This is the roundel of Pakistan.

These are probably Pakistani JF-17s on exhibition in Azerbaijan
The press release is heavily implying these are Azerbaijani JF-17s being "presented" to the President.

President of the Republic of Azerbaijan, Supreme Commander-in-Chief Ilham Aliyev was presented JF-17C (Block-III) multirole fighter jets on September 25, at Heydar Aliyev International Airport. These advanced, lightweight, all-weather aircraft, designed for both day and night operations, were developed as a joint venture between Pakistan Aeronautical Complex, Kamra and Chengdu Aircraft Industry Corporation of China.
The jets have already been integrated into the arsenal of Azerbaijan's Air Force.

What I believe is actually depicted are Pakistani JF-17s on display for the ADEX-2024 conference. From a press release the previous day...

Ilham Aliyev, President of the Republic of Azerbaijan, viewed the 5th Anniversary Azerbaijan International Defence Exhibition “ADEX-2024” and the 14th International Exhibition for Internal Security, Safety and Rescue Equipment "Securex Caspian" at the Baku Expo Center on September 24.

Baku Expo Center is adjacent to Heydar Aliyev International Airport where the photos were taken the next day.

If the JF-17 shown hadn't been rebadged, it might have been a token for the ceremony, and not one of those already in service.

@WeatherVane Yes, they sure are heavily implying these are Azerbaijani jets. Their display is not evidence in favor of the claim. My guess is someone in the Azerbaijani AF over-promised (lied) about how far long JF-17 procurement was, the President wanted a photo-op, and they had to borrow some JF-17s from Pakistan.

@WeatherVane Did a bit more sleuthing. I think they were there for a regional defense exhibition and the president decided to turn it into a photo op with the implication they're Azerbaijani JF-17s.
